# Jenkins List Subversion tags -plugin does not show all tags

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a strange problem using the subversion tags -plugin for Jenkins. I can only see the next level folders when specifying a path. So if set Repository URL to e.g /Project/Tags/, then I get only the following output:

```
Section1
Section2
Section3
```

The above folders are under /Tags/. However, The above folders also contain sub-folders, which again contain their own sub-folders, etc. I would expect the above output to be all folders under /Tags/, not just the topmost parent folders. Any ideas to why this is so?

Comment: same here, would like to specify the recursive depth for listing tags. I have the following structure. /tags/module1/1.0.0; /tags/module2/1.0.0; /moduleN/versionN. I would like to specify for ex, depth 2, on which the plugin should fetch util the version number.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to pick any of the sub-folders, whatever their depth, then your job would have to be smart enough to know in what folder it is, and to know what is the content of the folder.
Whereas, by offering you to only download a tag (because the sub-folders in /tags/ are SVN tags), the structure is predictable and always the same.